# How to prove multinomial partitioning

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

I was assigned an extra problem by my instructor (who's a grad student btw). So far, I know this question requires combinations and summation but I am so lost - I have no idea how to go about writing it or even starting it.

[A picture of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Eq9y.png)

Here's my current understanding of the problem: I have n items, and I want to put them into k subsets (where k^n) requires the use of the multinomial theorem.

Thanks and I appreciate any help or hints!!

Comment: Please [don’t use images instead of typing your formulas](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem)

[Type the text](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) of your exercise

Answer (score 1):

I guess you refer to the multinomial theorem:

$$(x_1+\ldots+x_k)^n = \sum_{n_1+\ldots+n_k=n} {n\choose n_1,\ldots,n_k} x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_k^{n_k}.$$

Put $x_1=\ldots=x_k=1$.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't exactly what I was looking for but I appreciate the help :)